# Find Video Game Title(s) Starring Certain Actor

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have this diagram of the IMDB

[image]

It illustrates the database relations and attributes behind the IMDB website.

I need to find all video game titles (which have KIND_TYPE_ID 6) that stars a certain actor. I've been at it for a while now and I can't really wrap my head around how to do this. I want to use the CAST_INFO.NAME attribute to figure it out and then just sort out by KIND_TYPE_ID but the catch is, that you cannot access cast info going through TITLE even though to me the diagram would indicate that you could.

I don't ask for the solution to be given to me, but more a push in the right direction. I have this idea of joining tables together and sort through that, but the issue is that none of these tables seems to be able to naturally join and still make sense.

Comment: Look for a cast-title join table (a table that has both title.id and cast_info.id as foreign key and probably not many other fields).

Answer (score 0):

**DISCLAIMER:** I may be wrong since not enough information can be found from the diagram, but on assuming that foreign keys are made as per table names, your problem can be solved.

As per the diagram, you should be able to join TITLE table to CAST_INFO table using a key.

Assuming 'TITLE_ID' to be a foreign key for CAST_INFO, you will join the two with:

```
SELECT * FROM TITLE
JOIN CAST_INFO ON CAST_INFO.TITLE_ID = TITLE.ID;
```

Now, since you need 'certain actor' and assuming that to be present in NAME table, you can then join the table with another key

```
SELECT * FROM TITLE
JOIN CAST_INFO ON CAST_INFO.TITLE_ID = TITLE.ID
JOIN NAME ON CAST_INFO.ID = NAME.CAST_INFO_ID;
```

At last, joining 'KIND_TYPE' table for your where condition:

```
SELECT * FROM TITLE
JOIN CAST_INFO ON CAST_INFO.TITLE_ID = TITLE.ID
JOIN NAME ON NAME.CAST_INFO_ID = CAST_INFO.ID
JOIN KIND_TYPE ON KIND_TYPE.TITLE_ID = TITLE.ID
WHERE KIND_TYPE.ID = 6
ORDER BY KIND_TYPE.ID;
```

You just need to figure out on which column the tables will be joined. :)

Comment: I fixed it without JOIN. I will post the Answer for others :D

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that `IN` is the new Jesus in SQL.

This piece of code did exactly as expected which was to return all video games the actor `Mads Mikkelsen` had been in (which was 1: Quantum of Solace).

```
SELECT title FROM IMDB.TITLE WHERE TITLE.ID IN
  (SELECT MOVIE_ID FROM IMDB.CAST_INFO WHERE PERSON_ID=
    (SELECT id FROM IMDB.NAME WHERE name='Mikkelsen, Mads')) AND KIND_ID=
      (SELECT id FROM IMDB.KIND_TYPE WHERE KIND='video game');
```